# AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objectss'

Tags: tensorflow, import, spacy, libraries

When I try to import tensorflow or any sort of deep learning models or libraries, it throws similar errors. Any suggestions on this please

I tried, uninstalling and reinstallin and downgraded but still throws different erors like

AttributeError: module 'this ' has no attribute 'this'

Comment: Please add your code that you are trying to run. and for the future please read the following article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide the minimal reproducible code to replicate the error. Please ensure you have installed tensorflow in your system properly by verifying through this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip). Let us know if the issue still persists.